# Finding the next Canvas id in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When looking for the next element id in Jquery the simplest solution is to use closest(element). but it is not working for Canvas and I don't know why.

```js
$('a.findNext').click(function() {
  debugger;
  var nextSectionWithId = $(this).closest("canvas").nextAll("canvas[id]:first");
  if (nextSectionWithId) {
    var sectionId = nextSectionWithId.attr('id');
    $("#test").text(sectionId)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section_1">
  <a href="#" class="findNext">Find</a>
</div>
<div></div>
<canvas id="section_3"></canvas>
<canvas id="section_4"></canvas>

<div id='test'></div>
```

Demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/jtdgo304/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.closest` will select the nearest *ancestor* matching the selector. But the `.findNext` element does not have a `canvas` ancestor.

If you want to get the next ancestor, you'll need to first navigate to an element that's a sibling of the canvas (which is the `#section_1` here), then use `.nextAll`.

You should also check the `.length` of the jQuery collection to see if it matches any elements.

```js
$('a.findNext').click(function() {
  const nextSectionWithId = $(this).parent().nextAll("canvas[id]:first");
  if (nextSectionWithId.length) {
    const sectionId = nextSectionWithId.attr('id');
    $("#test").text(sectionId)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section_1">
  <a href="#" class="findNext">Find</a>
</div>
<div></div>
<canvas id="section_3"></canvas>
<canvas id="section_4"></canvas>

<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: Issue with that is that'd find the *first* canvas among the children, not necessarily the *next* canvas. If it needs to be more general I think there needs to be a way to select the siblings, eg, if the container of the canvases (and everything else in the markup here) is `.container`, one could do `.closest('.container > *')`

Comment: Yes you're right, I realized afterwards they wanted the next one, still sounds unsatisfying to have to rely on the direct parent being a sibling of the targets. (I'm happy I don't have to be in such a situation, and the obvious "solution" would be to avoid putting oneself in).